# Rails - In sql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have two models, Books and Catalogs.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :catalogs
end

class Catalog < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

I need to find books that belong **only** to list of specific catalogs.
I have tried,

```
DEFAULT_CATALOGS = ["A","B"]
Book.joins(:catalogs).where("catalogname = ?",DEFAULT_CATALOGS)
```

but I am getting an exception 
Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s):

Comment: Shouldn't be catalogname => catalog_name?

Answer (score 0):

It should be either:

```
Book.joins(:catalogs).where("catalogs.catalogname IN (?)", DEFAULT_CATALOGS)
```

or:

```
Book.joins(:catalogs).where(:catalogs => {:catalogname => DEFAULT_CATALOGS})
```

Comment: Thanks, it now worked (with the first suggestion) but I get all the books that one of the catalogs they assigned to, are in default catalogs group. What I want to achieve is that I want the books that all their catalogs are in the default group. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Could you try to rephrase. I don't understand what you are saying.